# ExtJS app gives variables undefined error after sencha cmd app build

Tags: javascript, extjs, ecmascript-6, minify

We have an existing `ExtJS` app that works perfectly when not minified or merged into a single bundle file.

After we ran sencha app build command and created a `app-all.js` file, some screens are not working as before and is giving Error:

> Cannot read property 'xxxxx' of undefined.

A sample snippets that gives the above error is:

```
function(b){
  var a=b, c=a.something, d=c.somethingElse;
}
```

here, it says:

> cannot read property something of undefined.

Why does the behavior of the code change after the build?

Comment: Most likely a bug in minification library. I had those before ( not with Sencha Cmd tho) I would try to re-write it. For example try to define the variable on each new line - not all at once. But not sure if that will help.  Would also report a bug on Sencha Forum.

Comment: This application is huge and built over years. I am just trying to minify it now (I know it's way too late already). so rewriting all those lines is like a nightmare. any easy way out?

Answer (score 0):

The issue in my case was that there were some backup files of which had different name but the content was older version of the actual file to be loaded. For example, when application is not minified, say the file getting loaded is root.some.path.OneSampleFile.js.  When minified, another File OneSampleFileBackup.js was overwriting OneSampleFile as both the files said

```
Ext.Define('root.some.path.OneSampleFile')
```

Trying to figure out if there is any easier way to locate files that have duplicate declarations or to only include files whose ext define path and location matches, in the app-all.js build.